# Show that the product of countable many closed sets is closed.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that the product of countable many closed sets is closed.

Let $A_i, i \in I$ be the closed sets. I want to show that $A = \prod_i A_i$ is closed.

Now I found that the product can be expressed as $\prod_i A_i = \bigcap_i pr_i^{-1}(A_i)$ which would immediately prove the statement since arbitary intersection of closed sets is closed, but I cannot figure out how to prove the result and how the product can be expressed as an intersection of projection maps?

Comment: Closed *where*?

Comment: I assume that there is supposed to be a collection of spaces $X_j$. And $A_i$’s would be the subsets. @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: Do not merely say "closed".  Mention a topological space $X$ and say "closed in $X$".

Comment: I see. Perhaps the book I’m reading assumes this from the context.

Comment: I'm guessing, just before this in the book, there is a description of a "product topology", and it is understood that this is the topology to be used.

Comment: @Wondera Can you tell us the book you are reading, and where this question is? ("Lacking context" is one of the close reasons - the context of the book gives us the context of the question...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x \in \prod\limits_{i \in I} A_i$. Then by definition, for each $i \in I$, $pr_i(x) \in A_i$. So for all $i$, $x \in pr_i^{-1}(A_i)$. So $x \in \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} pr_i^{-1}(A_i)$.

Conversely, suppose that $x \in \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} pr_i^{-1}(A_i)$. Then for all $i \in I$, $x \in pr_i^{-1}(A_i)$. So for all $i$, $pr_i(x) \in A_i$. Then $x \in \prod\limits_{i \in I} A_i$.

Thus, we see that $\prod\limits_{i \in I} A_i = \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} pr_i^{-1}(A_i)$.

Answer (score 0):

$pr_i^{-1}(A_i)$ looks like $X \times \cdots \times X\times A_i \times X \times \cdots$ . Is the intersection now easier to make sense of?